# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of null

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, single-page-application

I am writing a form validation for email and for it it is giving following error - ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of null.
Following is the HTML code for Angular 5 Template driven form.

```html
<form name="form" #myForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit) = "onSubmit()">
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="firstName">First Name*</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstName" [(ngModel)]="firstName" #firstname="ngModel"   required minlength="6" />
                      <div *ngIf="firstname.touched && firstname.invalid">
                        <div *ngIf="firstname.invalid && firstname.errors.required" class="alert alert-danger">First name is mandatory</div>
                        <div *ngIf="firstname.invalid && firstname.errors.minlength" class="alert alert-danger">First name must have minimum 6 characters</div>
                    </div>

                      <div *ngIf="myForm.submitted && firstname.invalid">
                          <div *ngIf="firstname.invalid && firstname.errors.required">First name is mandatory</div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastName" [(ngModel)]="lastName"  #lastname="ngModel" required />
                      
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="email">Email</label>
                      <input type="email" class="form-control" name="myemail" [(ngModel)]="email" 
                      #myemail="ngModel" required myemail/>
                      <div *ngIf="myemail.touched">
                          <div *ngIf="myemail.invalid && myemail.errors?.required" class="alert alert-danger">Email is required</div>
                        <div *ngIf="myemail.errors.email && !myemail.errors.required" class="alert alert-danger">Email is not valid</div>
                        
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="selectcity">City</label>

                    <select name="city" class="form-control" [(ngModel)] = "cityvalue" required #cityselect = "ngModel">
                      <option value="Pune">Pune</option>
                      <option value="Mumbai">Mumbai</option>
                      <option value="Delhi">Delhi</option>
                      <option value="Surat">Surat</option>
                    </select>
                    <div *ngIf="cityselect.touched && cityselect.invalid">
                      <div *ngIf="cityselect.invalid && cityselect.errors.required" class="alert alert-danger">City name is mandatory</div>
                      
                  </div>
                </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="password">Password</label>
                      <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" [(ngModel)]="password" #mypassword="ngModel" minlength="6"/>
                      
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <button   class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
                  </div>
              </form>
```

Following is the code for email validation

```html
   <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="email">Email</label>
                      <input type="email" class="form-control" name="myemail" [(ngModel)]="email" 
                      #myemail="ngModel" required myemail/>
                      <div *ngIf="myemail.touched">
                          <div *ngIf="myemail.invalid && myemail.errors?.required" class="alert alert-danger">Email is required</div>
                        <div *ngIf="myemail.errors.email && !myemail.errors.required" class="alert alert-danger">Email is not valid</div>
                        
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

If I use "myemail.errors?.email" It works fine but does not show message "Email is not valid".
If I use "myemail.errors.email" it throws error shown above or in title.

I tried to use the pattern "pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+.[a-z]{2,4}$" " It worked for email.

Following is my question:
 **Why in template driven form of angular email is null error thrown?
 And How can we solve it.**

Comment: add email to formControlName="email"

Comment: @ORBIT I tried it gave following error :Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngModel" (""myemail" [(ngModel)]="email" 
                      formControlName="myemail"                      [ERROR ->]#myemail="ngModel" required myemail/>
                      <div *ngIf="myemail.touched">
           "): ng:///AppModule/RegistrationComponent.html@27:69

Comment: add same name for both email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be change to

```
<input type="email" class="form-control" name="myemail" [(ngModel)]="myemail" 
#myemail="ngModel" required />
```

Comment: Did not work gave error  - Uncaught Error: Cannot assign to a reference or variable!

Comment: It did not give error but the my original problem remains email is null. So no email invalid message